# use of atoi() function in c++

Tags: c++, atoi

when I pass a `string` variable in the below code, g++ gives an error:

> cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int atoi(const char*)’

My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "10";
    int b = atoi(a);
    cout<<b<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But if I change the code to :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[3] = "10";
    int b = atoi(a);
    cout<<b<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It works completely fine.

Please explain why `string` doesn't work. Is there any difference between `string a` and `char a[]`?

Comment: _"Is there any difference between string a and char a[]?"_ Yes. One is a `std::string` and one is not.

Comment: As the error message clearly says, a conversion is necessary.

Answer (score 12):

`atoi` is an older function carried over from C.

C did not have `std::string`, it relied on null-terminated char arrays instead.  `std::string` has a `c_str()` method that returns a null-terminated `char*` pointer to the string data.

```
int b = atoi(a.c_str());
```

In C++11, there is an alternative [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function that takes a `std::string` as an argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "10";
    int b = std::stoi(a);
    std::cout << b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need `#include <string>` to use `std::string` and `std::stoi()`.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice](why using namespace std is bad)

Comment: @EdHeal Yes it is, but that's outside the scope of OP's question.  I took what was already there and applied the least amount of changes to answer the question.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: Technically, you didn't actually answer the question that was asked (why `string` doesn't work with `atoi()`), you only provided an alternative code that works with `string`.

Comment: @EdHeal: that is *the* answer, yes.  But Trevor's answer does not actually explain that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a C style string.

I.e use `c_str()`

Change

```
int b = atoi(a);
```

to

```
int b = atoi(a.c_str());
```

PS:

This would be better - get the compiler to work out the length:

```
char a[] = "10";
```

Answer (score 2):

`atoi()` expects a null-terminated `char*` as input.  A `string` cannot be passed as-is where a `char*` is expected, thus the compiler error.  On the other hand, a `char[]` can decay into a `char*`, which is why using a `char[]` works.

When using a `string`, call its `c_str()` method when you need a null-terminated `char*` pointer to its character data:

```
int b = atoi(a.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between them.
For each one there are different functions:

### String

As said before, for `string` there is the `stoi` function:

```
string s("20");
cout << stoi(s) * 2; // output: 40
```

### char*

In the past, `atoi` used to handle `char*` conversion.

However, now `atoi` is replaced by `strtol` which gets 3 parameters:

1. `char*` of the characters to parse to `long`,
2. `char**` that returns pointer to after the parsed string,
3. `int` for the base the number should be parsed from (2, 10, 16, or whatever).

```
char c[]="20";
char* end;
cout << strtol(c, &end, 16); // output: 32
```

There are whole bunch of functions like `strtol` like `strtof`, `strtod`, or `strtoll` which converts to `float`, `double`, `long`, and `long long`.

The main advantages of those new functions are mostly error-handling, and multi-base support.

The main disadvantage is that there isn't a function that converts to `int`, only to `long` (besides other types).

For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866001/12893141

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation of [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), the function expects a *"pointer to the null-terminated byte string to be interpreted"* which basically is a C-style string. `std::string` is string type in C++ but it have a method `c_str()` that can return a C-string which you can pass to `atoi()`.

```
string a = "10";
int b = atoi(a.c_str());
```

But if you still want to pass `std::string` and your compiler supports C++ 11, then you can use [`stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

```
string a = "10";
int b = stoi(a);
```