# Checking whether input is number in C

Tags: c, input, numbers

I need to check whether the input is number. My code looks something like this:

```
int input;

while ( scanf(" %s %d", string, &input) != EOF) {

if ( isNotANumber(input) ) {
    printf("Not a number"); }

doSomethingElse(input, string);
}
```

EDIT: I need to be accepting input and calling the function doSomethingElse(input) until the user enters EOF.
isNotANumber is a mock function, I don't have that function, I'm asking how could I write it.

EDIT 2: Variable string needs to be a string, variable input needs to be an integer.

EDIT 3: I tried separating my code into this:

```
while (scanf(" %s", string) != EOF) {
    if (scanf("%d",&input) != 1) {
    printf("not a number");
}
doSomething();
}
```

But it stil doesn't work for input like "4a".

Comment: I think `isNotANumber(input)`  cannot inspect `input` in the loop.

Comment: As `input` is defined `int` its value will always and ever be an integer, at least as long `scanf()`  did not fail.

Comment: If you don't know that the input is a number, you cannot use scanf.  (Or, rather, you can use scanf, but if scanf doesn't read the input because it isn't a number, then you're going to have to read it some other way, so doing the scanf was pointless.)  You'll need to input the data some other way.  Try `fread` and then check if it is an integer using `strtol`.  BTW, do you mean "number", or "integer"?  Be precise.

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying clearly. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can change it as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define doSomethingElse(input) do{ printf("your input is %d\n", input); }while(0)

int main(void){
    int input;
    int status;

    while ((status = scanf("%d", &input)) != EOF) {
        if ( status == 0 ) {
            printf("Not a number\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n'); //clear input
        }
        else {
            doSomethingElse(input);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this can not check input like `123.456`. (accept `123`)
So, It is recommended to input with `fgets` and check with `strtol`.

---

As already pointed out, like `scanf(" %s %d", string, &input)` **can not check the input after the number**.

So, For convenience, check backward input.

```
char string[32], ch;
int input;
int status;


while ((status = scanf("%31s %d%c", string, &input, &ch )) != EOF) {
    if ( status == 3 && ch == '\n') {
        doSomethingElse(input);
    }
    else {
        printf("Not a number\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n'); //clear input
    }
}
```

---

Example using `fgets` and `strtol`
(`mystrtoi` has reorganized the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866001/971127) of chux. thanks)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define doSomethingElse(input) do{ printf("your input is %d\n", input); }while(0)

int mystrtoi(const char *str, int *err) {
    char *endptr;
    *err = errno = 0;
    long l = strtol(str, &endptr, 0);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *endptr != '\0' || str == endptr) {
        *err = 1;
    }
    // Only needed if sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)
    if (l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX) {
        *err = 1;
    }
    return (int) l;
}


int main(void){
    char line[128];
    char string1[32], string2[128];
    int num, err;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
//      if(2 != sscanf(line, "%31s %31s", string1, string2)){// or use strtok to split
        if(2 != sscanf(line, "%31s %127[^\n]", string1, string2)){
            printf("invalid input\n");
            continue;
        }
        num = mystrtoi(string2, &err);
        if(err) {
            printf("Not a number\n");
        }
        else {
            doSomethingElse(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've had to edit the code, how can I check my input now?

Comment: @Kate The situation does not change much. input fails if `status == 1`.

Comment: It still accepts input as "string 4a" and that should also be seen as "Not a number.". How can I fix that?

Comment: I already recommended to input with `fgets` and check with `strtol`.

Comment: I looked here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm . But I still don't see how I can use it in my case. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Kate validate using `strtol` [string convert to int sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22866001/971127)

Comment: The problem is that my scanf functions looks like this: scanf(" %s %d", string, &input). And now I don't know how to adjust it.

Comment: @Kate Do you necessarily have to use `scanf` ?

Comment: Not necessarily. But I don't know how to use fgets. I've separated my code into this: `while (scanf("%s", string) != EOF) { if (scanf("%d", input) != 1) { printf("Not an integer");} doSomething();}` But it still doesn't work properly for input like 4a.

Comment: @Kate Sample was added.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( scanf("%d", input) != EOF)
```

Your `scanf` code has two problems:

- `scanf` returns the number of successfully read item, not `EOF`. Here you want to check if `scanf` has successfully read one integer `input`
- `scanf` expects the address of the variable

You should re-write that line as:

```
while ( scanf("%d", &input) == 1 )
```

Comment: if your `scanf` is successful, then `input` is already a number