# C. invalid operands to binary * (have ‘char *’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c

Hy! I learn #define in C. My program about the absolute value. I have 2 files: ft_abs.h:

```
#ifndef FT_ABS_H
# define FT_ABS_H

# define ABS(Value) ((Value < 0) ? (Value * (-1)) : (Value))

#endif
```

and main.c:

```
#include "ft_abs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s", ABS(argv[1]));
    return (0);
}
```

compile

```
gcc -o abs ft_abs.h main.c
```

and...

> In file included from main.c:2:0: main.c: In function ‘main’:
>   ft_abs.h:16:41: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘char *’ and
>   ‘int’)  # define ABS(Value) ((Value < 0) ? (Value * (-1)) : (Value))
>                                             main.c:17:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘ABS’
>        printf("%s", ABS(argv[1]));

When I change (Value * (-1)) to (-Value) it is not work too (wrong type argument to unary minus). If I change (-Value) to (Value) all ok, but it is nonsense. How should I change the code to make it work (using define of course)?

Comment: What result do you expect by taking the absolute value of a c-string? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is not relevant to your problem, but I'd replace `(Value * (-1))` by `(-Value)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Both lack the parentheses around the argument, which are important in macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1]` is of type `char *`. It does not make any sense to calculate the absolute value. You probably want to transform the argument to an `int` type and then calculate the absolute value.

```
printf("%d", ABS(strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)));
```

In addition you should always put parentheses around your arguments when writing macros.

```
#define ABS(Value) (((Value) < 0) ? ((Value) * (-1)) : (Value))
```

Comment: @PeteLensky `atoi` has no error handling as descriped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866001/9017315). `strtol` is probably the better option.

Comment: These facts will be useful.