# Convert char String to an int but not possible to convert a char from an char string to an int?

Tags: c, atoi

```
char input[5] = "12345";

printf("Convert to int valid %d", atoi(input));
printf("Convert to int invalid %d", atoi(input[1])); // program crash
```

Is there a solution to convert an char "slice" of an char string into an int?
Short description:

User inputs a string with values for example: 1, 2 3 4 ,5
Iam formating that string to 12345
With each number i want to continue to work with the index of an array.

Comment: If you're looking to convert a character to an integer, just use `input[1] - '0'`

Comment: `char input[5] = "12345";`Should be `char input[] = "12345";` - Get the compiler to work out the length and it will allow for the null character

Comment: @EdHeal sorry was an issue here in the sample. In my actual code i havnt forgott about the end of the char array "\0"

Comment: When using a *string literal* initializer, let the compiler fill in the size, e.g. `char input[] = "12345";` (that way you can't make a mistake) If you need to determine the size of the array in the scope where it was declared, then `sizeof input / sizeof *input` will do. But if you pass `input` as a parameter, it is converted to a pointer to the first element and `sizeof (a_pointer)` will no longer return the number of bytes in `input`, it will simply tell you how many bytes a pointer requires on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "how to access a substring in the `char []` array", you can use pointer arithmetic:

```
char input[6] = "12345";
printf("strtol(input + 1) = %d\n", strtol(input + 1, NULL, 10)); // Output = "2345";
```

Few things to note though:

1. Your array should be 6 elements long to hold the null terminator
2. `atoi` shouldn't be used at all; `strtol` is a better function for the task of converting a string to a signed integer; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865622/atoi-vs-atol-vs-strtol-vs-strtoul-vs-sscanf) for more info.

Also, to convert a single character to an `int`:

```
if(isdigit(c))
{
     c -= '0';
}
```

The relation that a textual representation of a digit is exactly `'0'` higher than the numeric value of that digit is guaranteed to hold for every character set supported by C.

Comment: You can't grab the first character without modifying the contents of the array this way.

Comment: Thank you for the information havnt forgott about "\0" terminator in my actual code. 
Will have a look into strtol.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not entirely sure what you’re trying to tell me

Comment: See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) to understand why `c - '0'` provides the integer value for a single digit.

Answer (score 2):

To properly convert an arbitrary slice, you have to either make a copy or modify the string by inserting a `\0` after the slice. The latter may not be an option, depending on where the string is stored.

To make a copy, allocate an array big enough to hold the slice and a `\0`. If you know the size of the slice at compile time, you can allocate on the stack:

```
char slice[2];
```

Otherwise, you'll have to allocate dynamically:

```
char *slice;

slice = malloc(2);
```

Stack allocated slices do not need to be deallocated, but dynamically allocated ones should be freed as soon as they are no longer needed:

```
free(slice);
```

Once you have the slice allocated, copy the portion of interest and terminate it with `\0`:

```
strncpy(slice, s + 1, 1);
slice[1] = '\0';
atoi(slice);
```

This technique will pretty much always work.

If your slice always ends with the string, you don't need to make a copy: you just need to pass a pointer to the start of the slice:

```
atoi(s + 1);
```

Modifying the string itself probably won't work, unless it's in writeable memory. If you're sure this is the case, you can do something like:

```
char tmp;

tmp = s[1];
s[1] = '\0';
atoi(s);
s[1] = tmp;
```

If you were sure but the memory wasn't writeable, your program will seg-fault.

For the special case where your slice is exactly one character long, you can use the fact that characters are numbers:

```
s[0] - '0'
```

Note that `'0' !='\0'` and that this won't work if your machine uses EBCDIC or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well for this project / case the slice will never be longer then one charakter input[i] - '0' totally made it. But ill look into the other options as well for future projects where a charakter could be longer then exactly one charakter (eg. 10, 11 , 12)