# Determining Data Type Of User Entered Value

Tags: c, structure, unions, union-types

I was reading one of the application of "Unions" of creating mixed data types. Example

```
typedef union {
int x;
float y;
}mix;
mix arr[100];
```

Each element of array `arr[100]` can store either a `int` or a `float` type value. But suppose I want to take a input from user and store it in `arr[ ]` and I won't know that either user is going to enter a `float`or an `int` value. So I don't know which statement from the following I should choose to store that input from user.

1.`scanf ("%d",&arr[0].x);`

**OR**

2.`scanf ("%f",&arr[0].y);`

And similar problem arises when I want to print that value.

I know I can solve this problem using a **"tag field"**. So I can do it as

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union {
int x;
float y;
}mix;
mix arr[100];

int main ()
{
int k; // tag field
puts("Mention 1 if you want to enter integer and 0 if you want to enter float value");
scanf ("%d",&k);
if (k)
{
scanf ("%d",&arr[0].x);
printf ("%d is the entered integer value\n",arr[0].x);
}
else
{
scanf ("%f",&arr[0].y);
printf ("%f is the entered float value\n",arr[0].y);
}

}
```

But here user is telling the type of data he is gonna enter(with the help of 0 or 1). I want to know: Is there any way in C language that compiler can automatically detect the type of data user is entering and according run either 1st or 2nd `scanf` statement without help of user? **OR** Is there any predefined function present in library for doing that?

Also tell if you have any another intresting way of doing this program.

Comment: Read text into a _string_ and then parse it as `int`, and then as `float`:  4 outcomes possible.  both, float, int, neither. If both, I'd prefer `int`.

Comment: Would you classify input text  `"4294967296\n"` as an out-of-range-`int` or a `float`?  What about `"2147483647.0\n"`.  Is that an exact `int` or imprecise `float`?

Comment: @chux Thanks for your line "Read text into a _string_ and then parse it as `int`, and then as `float`". This has clicked an idea in me.

Comment: @chux "Would you classify input text  `"4294967296\n"` as an out-of-range-`int` or a `float`?" **:** I was just trying  this program for small values (4 to 5 digits), So we can consider it as out of range.

Comment: @chux " What about `"2147483647.0\n"`.  Is that an exact `int` or imprecise `float`? " : It should be considered as float.

Comment: And how would your program later know which type to use?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you I guess...

```
float num;
printf("Enter number\n");
scanf("%f",&num);
if((num - (int)num)== 0) //(int)num : Type casting
    printf("Entered number is of int type\n");
else
    printf("Entered number is of float type\n");
```

Comment: It works...thanks. But only problem with your solution is that it treats a number like `5.00` as integer but it should be a float type. But anyway your answer helped me. One upvote for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Determining Data Type Of User Entered Value

Read as a line `fgets()`and the parse with `strtol(), strtof()`.

Untested code, read comments.

```
puts("Mention 1 if you want to enter integer and 0 if you want to enter float value");
char buffer[100];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  // OK we have an input line of text now as a string
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n

  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long lval = strtol(buffer, &endptr);
  // If conversion occurred and no text at the end ...
  if (endptr > buffer && *endptr == '\0') {
    // An integer type!
    if (errno == ERANGE) puts("Integer value out of range");
    printf("Integer value: %ld\n", lval);
  } else {
    errno = 0;
    float = strtof(buffer, &endptr);
    if (endptr > buffer && *endptr == '\0') {
      // A float
      if (errno == ERANGE) puts("float value out of range");
      printf("float value: %g\n", f);
    } else
      puts("Non-numeric input");
    }
  }
```

For a `int mystrtoi(const char *str)`, see [ref code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866001/2410359).