# `strtoul()` What is the correct return value for very "negative" strings?

Tags: c

This is an [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). 
I researched the issue, found the result curious, and posted my findings.

---

What value should "very negative" strings return from `strtoul()`: `1`, `ULONG_MAX` or what?

---

**`strtol()`**

For strings representing numeric values like `"123"`, `strtol()` behaves as expected.  Strings (blue) `[LONG_MIN ... LONG_MAX]` convert to their expected `long` value.  Strings (yellow) above `LONG_MAX` convert to `LONG_MAX` and set `errno==ERANGE`. Strings below `LONG_MIN` convert to `LONG_MIN` and set `errno==ERANGE`.

**`strtoul()` positive**

For strings representing numeric values like `"123"`,  `strtoul()` also behaves as expected.  Strings (red) `[0 ... ULONG_MAX]` convert to their expected `unsigned long` value.  Strings (green) above `ULONG_MAX` convert to `ULONG_MAX` and set `errno==ERANGE`.

> If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type).  C17dr § 7.22.1.4 5

**`strtoul()` negative**

For strings (red) `[-ULONG_MAX ... -1]`, the conversion negates the positive conversion and adds `ULONG_MAX + 1` (like the typical assignment of a negative value to an *unsigned*) and does not set `errno`.  This is a bit surprising, but that is how the specs defines it.

***`strtoul()` very negative - the problem***

For strings (green) less than`-ULONG_MAX`, I'd expect the conversion to be handled like smaller negative values described above: the conversion negates the positive conversion (`ULONG_MAX` due to overflow) and adds `ULONG_MAX + 1`.  Expected result `1` (or maybe `0`) with `errno == ERANGE`. Yet exercising `strtoul()` resulted in `ULONG_MAX`.

What is correct?

[image: strtoul]

**Test code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long strtol_test(const char *s, int base) {
  printf("\n");
  int width = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld", LONG_MIN);
  printf("base:%2d \"%s\"\n", base, s);

  char *endptr_signed;
  errno = 0;
  long val_signed = strtol(s, &endptr_signed, base);
  int errno_signed = errno;

  char *endptr_unsigned;
  errno = 0;
  unsigned long val_unsigned = strtoul(s, &endptr_unsigned, base);
  int errno_unsigned = errno;

  if (val_signed < 0 || (unsigned long) val_signed != val_unsigned
      || endptr_signed != endptr_unsigned || errno_signed != errno_unsigned) {
    printf("  signed  val:%*ld end:%2td e:%s\n", width, val_signed,
        endptr_signed - s, strerror(errno_signed));
    printf("unsigned  val:%*lu end:%2td e:%s\n", width, val_unsigned,
        endptr_unsigned - s, strerror(errno_unsigned));
    return 1;
  }

  printf("    both  val:%*ld end:%2td e:%s\n", width, val_signed,
      endptr_signed - s, strerror(errno_signed));
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  char s[][50] = {"-ULONG_MAX1", "-ULONG_MAX", "LONG_MIN1", "LONG_MIN", "-1",
      "-0", "42", "LONG_MAX", "LONG_MAX1", "ULONG_MAX", "ULONG_MAX1", "x"};
  snprintf(s[0], sizeof *s, "-%lu", ULONG_MAX);
  s[0][strlen(s[0]) - 1]++;
  snprintf(s[1], sizeof *s, "-%lu", ULONG_MAX);
  snprintf(s[2], sizeof *s, "%ld", LONG_MIN);
  s[2][strlen(s[2]) - 1]++;
  snprintf(s[3], sizeof *s, "%ld", LONG_MIN);

  snprintf(s[7], sizeof *s, "%ld", LONG_MAX);
  snprintf(s[8], sizeof *s, "%ld", LONG_MAX);
  s[8][strlen(s[8]) - 1]++;
  snprintf(s[9], sizeof *s, "%lu", ULONG_MAX);
  snprintf(s[10], sizeof *s, "%lu", ULONG_MAX);
  s[10][strlen(s[10]) - 1]++;

  strcpy(s[11], s[0]);
  s[11][strlen(s[11]) - 1]++;

  int n = sizeof s / sizeof s[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    strtol_test(s[i], 0);
  }
}
```

**Sample output**

```
base: 0 "-18446744073709551616"
  signed  val:-9223372036854775808 end:21 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val:18446744073709551615 end:21 e:Numerical result out of range

base: 0 "-18446744073709551615"
  signed  val:-9223372036854775808 end:21 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val:                   1 end:21 e:No error

base: 0 "-9223372036854775809"
  signed  val:-9223372036854775808 end:20 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val: 9223372036854775807 end:20 e:No error

base: 0 "-9223372036854775808"
  signed  val:-9223372036854775808 end:20 e:No error
unsigned  val: 9223372036854775808 end:20 e:No error

base: 0 "-1"
  signed  val:                  -1 end: 2 e:No error
unsigned  val:18446744073709551615 end: 2 e:No error

base: 0 "-0"
    both  val:                   0 end: 2 e:No error

base: 0 "42"
    both  val:                  42 end: 2 e:No error

base: 0 "9223372036854775807"
    both  val: 9223372036854775807 end:19 e:No error

base: 0 "9223372036854775808"
  signed  val: 9223372036854775807 end:19 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val: 9223372036854775808 end:19 e:No error

base: 0 "18446744073709551615"
  signed  val: 9223372036854775807 end:20 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val:18446744073709551615 end:20 e:No error

base: 0 "18446744073709551616"
  signed  val: 9223372036854775807 end:20 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val:18446744073709551615 end:20 e:Numerical result out of range

base: 0 "-18446744073709551617"
  signed  val:-9223372036854775808 end:21 e:Numerical result out of range
unsigned  val:18446744073709551615 end:21 e:Numerical result out of range
```

Comment: I'm very much confused. I'm expecting strtoul to stop at a leading - and never parse a digit, so very negative is not a thing.

Comment: @Joshua Expecting `strtoul` to stop at a leading `'-'` differs from how `strtoul()` is specified. "If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the resulting value is the negative of the converted value; for functions whose return type is an unsigned integer type this action is performed in the return type."  Try `strtoul("-2", 0, 0);`.

Answer (score 5):

A range error result is always `ULONG_MAX` for `strtoul()`.

This is unlike `strtol()` whose return value is `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX`, depending on the sign of the range error.

It is fairly simple, for strings like `"-18446744073709551616"`, since the correct (positive) value is outside the range, `ULONG_MAX` is returned and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.  No provision exists on a range error for `strtoul()` to provide any other answer.

> ... If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, ... `ULONG_MAX`, ... is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`. C17dr § 7.22.1.4 8

Thus `strtoul()` produces a non-error value when the string is in the `[-ULONG_MAX ... +ULONG_MAX]` range.  The converted result is an `unsigned long` `[0 ...  ULONG_MAX]`.  An error result is always `ULONG_MAX`.