# Strtol doesn't set errno on overflow conversion

Tags: c

My strtol function fails to set errno during overflown conversion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    errno = 0;
    int e = strtol("1000000000000000", NULL, 10);
    printf("%d %d\n", errno, e);

    return 0;
}
```

returns

```
0 -1530494976
```

What do I do wrong?

Compiler

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2
```

Options

```
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 -O2
```

Comment: What compiler (and its version) are you using? Did you include all the necessary headers?

Comment: What does the man page say is the return type of `strol`?

Comment: Ok, compiler and headers added

Comment: `int` coercion happens outside of `strtol`, so `strtol` can't detect range error anyway.

Comment: Example [`strtoi()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the implementation of `strtol()` but there is with your code.

The return type of this function is `long` (see the trailing `l`) and apparently the value `1000000000000000` can be represented by the `long` integer type. However the return value is assigned to `e` whose type is `int` which is unable to represent this value. What then happens is implementation-defined.

So change `int e` to `long e` and `"%d %d\n"` to `"%d %ld\n"`. If you want to keep it as `int`, then you have to check if the value is outside of its range of representable values by yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>  // for INT_{MIN,MAX}
int
main(void)
{
    errno = 0;
    long f = strtol("1000000000000000", NULL, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        puts("value not representable by long (or int)");
    } else if (f < INT_MIN || f > INT_MAX) {
        puts("value not representable by int");
    } else {
        int e = f;
        printf("%d\n", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you possibly know if there is a function for normal int conversion, with overflow detection?

Comment: @Krzysztofik: I've added an example.

Comment: @cremno Actually, it was a brain fart. You're right, this is LP64, not LLP64.

Comment: @cremno Isn't `long` equal in size to `int`? Tested your code, see http://ideone.com/awPacv.

Comment: @Philip Dahnen `long` has _at least_ the range of `int`.  There are the same on many platform, yet differ on others - as allowed by the C spec.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like both Microsoft [1] and Apple [2] implementations have the setting of `errno` commented out.

[1] http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtol.c.htm

[2] http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/strtol.c

Comment: He's using GCC on Ubuntu.

Comment: `strtol` can't detect `int` coercion which happens outside of `strtol`

Comment: It's also not the Visual C++ CRT source code and the Apple link looks like kernel and not libc code.