# Code can't get an n-digit numbers from a string in C

Tags: c, string.h

I wanna ask how it can not get integer from a string

for example, here are my code:

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "ababbababa-1998";
    int nr = atoi(str);
    printf("%d\n", nr);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

when running, it print out 0 but not 1998, how can I fix it ?

Comment: you can calculate it using the ASCII number

Comment: No, i want to put 1998 to the nr variable, not get a single character and convert

Comment: You can store all the numbers in a char[] and then convert it into an integer.

Comment: If string format is fixed (like, "some_string-sume_number"), then you can use sscanf(string, "%s-%d", temp_str, &nr));

Comment: yes, but it could cause error format

Comment: Why expect code to somehow print 1998 and not -1998?

Comment: @STEPHENbui See my updated answer below. It is a simple approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use [strtok](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "ababbababa-1998";
    char * const first_part = strtok(str, "-");
    if (first_part == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    char * const second_part = strtok(NULL, "-");
    if (second_part == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    int nr = atoi(second_part);
    printf("%d\n", nr);
    return 0;
}
```

You can look at [Why is there no strtoi in stdlib.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181432/why-is-there-no-strtoi-in-stdlib-h) for error check atoi.

Comment: Is your strtok(str) usage valid?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more robust to just go through the string looking for the first digit rather than relying on `strtok`?

Comment: @MayurK yep I totally forget the delimiter

Comment: @John3136 if there is a digit in the string before "-", that will fail. I choice strtok to show him a very simple way to do a parser.

Comment: @Stargateur Not enough info has been provided for either of us to know we're right.

Comment: @Stargateur i don't understand at line 7, why strtok(NULL,"-") but not strtok(str,"-") ?

Comment: @STEPHENbui read the man of strtok. you only need to give one time the str that you want to parse to strtok after it will give you the rest at each call. If strtok send you NULL, there is nothing left.

Answer (score 1):

Keep walking down `str()` until code finds *something* numeric using `strtol()`.

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "ababbababa-1998";
    char *p = str; 

    char *endptr;
    while (*p) {
      long number = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
      // Was conversion successful?
      if (endptr != p) {
        printf("%ld\n", number);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }
      p++;
    }
    puts("No conversion");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ASCII '0'

int
main(void) {
    char const str[] = "ababbababa-1998";
    int i, result = 0;

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            result *= 10;
            result += str[i] - ASCII;
        }
    }

    printf("number = %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may be worth using a larger `INITSIZE` (e.g. 128, 256, etc..) and use a static buffer to avoid the `malloc`, `realloc` overhead. (there isn't anything wrong with dynamic allocation, it just adds overhead and complexity). You may also want to stop adding to `nr` after you have found digits, and then find a subsequent non-digit. (e.g. if you had a string `"aaaaa-1998aaaaa-1999"`) You could use a simple flag for that purpose. Just thoughts, not criticisms.

Comment: Yeah thanks for suggestion @DavidC.Rankin, I think this approach is too complicated. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Copy most of the string just to convert it to a number? Rubbish! `if (isdigit(array[i]) { total *= 10; total += array[i]; }`

Comment: Changed it @John3136. I overlooked this simple approach, cheers.

Comment: Obviously that should be `total += array[i] - '0';` - Just notcied you already did that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all the numeric digits from a string you could use this function I created.

You will need these header files for this function to work.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

```c
void getNumbers(char data[]) {
   int index = 0;
   char current;

   for( int i = 0; i < strlen(data); ++i ) {
      current = data[i];
      if (current >= 48 && current <= 57) {
         data[index++] = current;
      }
   }
    data[index] = '\0';
}
```

You can use the above function like this.

```c
char foobar[] = "1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I";

getNumbers(foobar);

printf("%s", foobar);
```

The above code will output **123456789**