# How to read a string with whitespaces and a int in the same line in c

Tags: c, text-files, scanf

How can i read a text file like this one:

```
Acqua Naturale 200
Coca Cola 100
Bibite 300
```

and store in a string `Acqua naturale` and `Coca Cola` and their int value in a int variable, using `sscanf()`.

The example code is this:

```
struct Test
{
 char name[16];
 int id;
};


 char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));

 while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(struct Test), filep))
    {
      if(sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", p.name, &p.id) == 2)
      {
        //do something with data

      }
    }
```

Comment: Uhm, the size of the data you allocate is to small. The size of your structure is very likely going to be 20 bytes, which is not enough if the number is more than four digits.

Comment: As for your problem with the string, the [`sscanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format `"%s"` reads a *space delimited* string.

Comment: Should `"7-up 100"` parse into `"7-up"` and 100?  What about `"abc4 123"`.  Is  `"xyz456"` valid to parse into `"xyz"` 456?

Comment: Here is some very good (though more general) advice on reading input of unpredicatable "syntax": http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq

Comment: It is not recommended to edit your question with an answer.  It you want to answer your own question, put it in the answer section, and mark it as answered.  And by basic tenants of courtesy, changing the nature of your question after the fact to accommodate your answer is bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution using `strtok()`, `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, `atoi()` and `isdigit()`. I am using linked list to store the data, so i think it is a specific solution. Ignore the parameter of the function `Load()` and the function `CreateNewNodeOfList()`.

```
void Load(HeadNode *pp) // ignore parameter
{
  FILE *f;
  struct Test p;
  char * buffer;
  char * token;
  char name[32] = "";
  if(!(f = fopen(PATH, "r")))
  {
    perror("Errore");
    exit(-1);
  }

  buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(struct Test), f))
    {
    for(token = strtok(buffer, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " "))
      {
          if(isdigit(token[0]))
            {
              p.id = atoi(token);
            }
            else
            {
              strcat(p.name, token);
              strcat(p.name, " ");
            }
      }
        CreateNewNodeOfList(p, pp); //ignore this function 
        strcpy(p.name, "");
    }

free(buffer);
fclose(f);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To separate "Acqua Naturale 200" into "Acqua Naturale" and 200 is a problem of looking for an integer at the end of the line.

Various approaches.

Perhaps look for last space separator,

OP nicely reads a *line* and then attempts to parse - this is better than `scanf()`.

Note that OP's buffer size is too small.  Consider `"abcdefghijklmno -2000000000\n"`, valid input which needs size 15 + 1 + 11 + 1 + 1 bytes.  Certainly that is more than `sizeof(struct Test)` as the text of a `int` may need more space than the binary encoded `int` (e.g. 2, 4 or 8 bytes).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

... 

  FILE *filep;
  struct Test p;
  //                        p.name    sp  int  \n  \0
  #define LINE_SIZE (sizeof p.name  + 1 + 11 + 1 + 1)
  char buffer[LINE_SIZE *2]; // No need to be stingy with temp buffer space, go for x2

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, filep)) {
    char *last_space = strrchr(buffer, ' ');
    if (last_space == NULL || (last_space - buffer) >= sizeof p.name ||
        sscanf(last_space, "%d", &p.id) == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Bad input '%s'\n", buffer);
      break;
    }
    memcpy(p.name, buffer, last_space - buffer);
    p.name[last_space - buffer] = '\0';

    // Do something with `p`
  }
```

---

More robust code would use a [strtoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359) and look for extra junk after the number as in `"xxx 122zzz"`.  Excessively long lines should be detected too.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to write code to read this file, you should think a little more about how the file is defined -- *precisely* how it's defined.

Informally, the definition of the file is "the first column is a string possibly containing whitespace, and the second column is an integer".  But what separates the columns?

If the columns are separated by whitespace, and if the first column can contain whitespace, then the first column isn't really the first column, it's potentially multiple columns.  That is, the line

```
Coca Cola 100
```

really contains three columns.

So if we want to go down this road, we have to try to differentiate between a second column that's an integer, and a first column that (though it might contain whitespace) does not look like an integer.

But if we go down that road, we have two pretty significant problems:

1. It's hard to code.  It's probably impossible to code satisfactorily using `scanf` or `sscanf` alone.
2. It's still ambiguous.  What if Coca Cola comes out with a new product "Coca Cola 2020"?  Then we'll have a line like

   `Coca Cola 2020 50`

So my bottom line is, if it was me, I wouldn't even try to write code to parse this file format.  I would come up with a cleaner, less ambiguous file format, perhaps

```
Coca Cola, 100
```

or

```
"Coca Cola",100
```

or

```
Coca Cola|100
```

and then write some clean and simple code to parse that.  (I probably still wouldn't use `scanf`, though; I'd probably use something more like `strtok`.  See also [this chapter](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html) in my C Programming notes.)

---

Addendum: the other road to potentially go down is to count columns from the right-hand edge.  In this case, you could write code to, in effect, say that the product name is in columns 1 to N-1, and the count is column N.  This can work as long as there's at most one "column" containing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick observations,

- `strtok()` over `sscanf()` is a better choice given this particular task.
- Unless there is only one record (data line) in the input file, an array of `struct` (as opposed to a single instance) is needed to contain the data.

*Rational:*
The more defined and predictable the syntax of a source file, the less complex it is to parse. Your file, as described has predictable contents.   With limited variability in syntax, *tokenizing* the record, using the *[strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* function is a good choice.

For what you are doing, the only variability in your file content would be the number of lines, and the number of alpha strings preceding the numeric string at the end.  The rest assumes space separated sub-strings within each line, with ***only*** the last having numeric content.  So one approach that would accommodate this type of file might use run-time memory creation for an array of `struct`, based on number of lines to process, and the `strtok()` function to read through the elements, storing each based on the type of string it is (either alpha or numeric).

*Example approach:*

file: x.txt contains the following:

> Acqua Naturale 200
>   Coca Cola 100
>   Bibite 300
>   Nesbits Gold 400
>   Fanta Iced Orange 500
>   Coca Cola Cherry Cream 600

```
char filename[] = {".\\x.txt"};

typedef struct {
    char name[200]; // add plenty of space
    int id;
}TEST;

void PopulateTest(TEST *t, char *file);//populate struct with content of file.
int GetLines(char *name);//get line count

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int lineCount = GetLines(filename);//get lines in file
    int i;

    TEST *test;//to create a variable number of instances of TEST

    test = calloc(lineCount, sizeof(TEST));
    if(test)
    {
        PopulateTest(test, filename);
    }
    for(i=0;i<lineCount;i++)
    {
        ;//do something with results    
    }
    free(test);

    return 0;
}

void PopulateTest(TEST *t, char *file)
{
    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char *tok = NULL;
    char line[200] = {0};
    char accum[200] = {0};
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
        {
            tok = strtok(line, " ");
            while(tok)// this loop accommodates a variable number of fields within each line 
            {
                if(isdigit(tok[0]))//test for sub-string content
                {
                    num = atoi(tok);
                }
                else               //read string segments and reconstruct string,
                {
                    strcat(accum, tok);
                    strcat(accum, " ");
                }
                tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
            strcpy(t[i].name, accum);//populate struct element members with parsed data.
            t[i].id = num;
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return; 
}

int GetLines(char *name)
{
    int count = 0;
    char line[200] = {0};
    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
        {
            count++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some misconceptions here.

- The input file appears to be a text file. If so, you cannot read the `sizeof` a struct from it, since that would assume binary format, not text which is longer. Instead of malloc, just allocate `buffer` as "large enough", for example `char buffer[200];`.
- Even in case of a binary file, you should never read/write a struct directly to/from a file. This is because structs can contain padding bytes to fix alignment, and those can be located anywhere, in a non-portable manner. So if one program writes the file and another reads it, it will break. The common way to read/write structs is to "serialize" and "de-serialize" by reading/writing each individual member at a time.
- So instead read the whole line as text into `buffer`, then parse through it. `sscanf` is a rather blunt tool for this unless you are certain of the buffer format. Instead you can search for the last space `' '` in the string and take anything before it as the name (make sure it is less than 15 characters + 1 null terminator), and everything after the space you pass to `strtol` which converts it to `int`.