# Convert char to int in C and then printf the value as int?

Tags: c, int

I keep getting these strange negative values when I run the code. Does anyone know what they are and how to get just an int (For example 10, 20, 8...)? Why do I always get a different and wrong value? When I run the code with arguments 2 and 3 it should output 10...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int h;
  int a;
  int b;
  a = (int) argv[1];
  b = (int) argv[2];
  if (argc == 3) {
    h = 2 * (a + b);
    printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is %d\n", h);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <arguments>\n", argv[0]);
  }
}

Output:
The perimeter of the rectangle is -1874251136
or
The perimeter of the rectangle is -1424723328
or
The perimeter of the rectangle is -940059169
```

Comment: Er... you're casting `char *` variables to `int`? Why? What in the world is that supposed to accomplish? You need to be using `strtol()` or something along those lines if you want to convert a string holding a number to an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test too late**

`if(argc==3){` tests for required `argc`, but unfortunately after using `argv[1], argv[2]`.  Move test before and exit if not as needed.  Note: good use of error message to `stderr`.

```
if (argc != 3) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <arguments>\n", argv[0]);
  return -1; // or return EXIT_FAILURE
}
```

**Incorrect conversion**

Code is converting the pointer and not the referenced text.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// a = (int)argv[1];
a = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Robust code would use `strtol()`  or perhaps roll your own [`strtoi()'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is an array of *pointers* to `char`. I.e. it's an array of *strings*. The string `"1"` is *not* equal to the integer `1` (or even the character `'1'`). The fact that you're doing a cast should almost always be a red flag.

To convert a string to a number use the [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function.

And always remember to check `argc` *before* accessing `argv`.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = (int)argv[2]
```

The `(int)` is a cast of the pointer value -- it just converts the type

Instead try use `atoi` or `strtol` to convert a string to an integer value.