# How should I verify that an integer value passed in from argv won't overflow?

Tags: c

I have a program that requires the user to enter an integer as a command line argument, in the form of `./program 100`.

Obviously this will read the value in as a string, so I need to parse it to an integer. I have to ensure that the input value won't overflow an integer variable. I have read about `strtol()`, but it works with `long` variables and I have to stick with a regular `int`.

Is there anything similar that can be used for an `int`?

Comment: Use `strtol` and compare to INT_MAX/MIN.

Comment: `if (longvalue > INT_MAX) /* overflow */;` don't forget to `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: @pmg check would fail for platforms when `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) = true`.

Comment: @SergeyA Why would it fail?

Comment: @SergeyA: hopefully they would catch the overflow when dealing with `strtol()`; before comparing the long (same as int) to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. because if long is int, longvalue will never be bigger than INT_MAX, so the whole check will be removed.

Comment: @pmg, you can do it in a single check by just comparing for `>= INT_MAX`. This will always work.

Comment: @SergeyA Which is fine I guess?

Comment: @EugeneSh. means the overflow (which will result in value set to INT_MAX) will not be caught on it's own? Unless you check for both errno and value.

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, apparently one should handle `strtol` errors too. I assumed OP is already aware of that when mentioned using `strtol`.

Comment: Did you check with -->  malloc(sizeof(int))

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess I was willing to use the threshold value as a sole indicator of overflow (without additional check for errno)

Comment: check `if ((int)value != value) error()` beside the usual `strtol()` related `-ERANGE` overflows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `strtol` for this.  You'll first need to check if this function fails to convert the value.  If it convert successfully, then check if the value is in the range of `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`:

```
errno = 0;
long x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
if (errno) {
    perror("conversion failed");
} else if (x < INT_MIN) {
    printf("value too small\n");
} else if (x > INT_MAX) {
    printf("value too big\n");
} else {
    printf("value = %ld\n", x);
}
```

Note that this will work whether `long` is the same size as `int` or larger.

If `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`, the `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` checks will catch the cases where the value fits in a `long` but not an `int`.  If `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)`, an out of range value will result in `errno` being set to non-zero to catch the error, and the `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` cases will never be true.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the ranges of `int` and `long` that are relevant here, not their sizes. In the presence of padding bits, it's possible for `int` and `long` to have the same size, but for `long` to have a wider range. (Few if any implementations actually use padding bits, though.)

Comment: `if (errno) {` is not a sufficient test to detect "conversion failed" as `errno` can still be 0.

Comment: @KeithThompson C++20 makes padding bits illegal and two's complement mandatory representation for signed integers. This decision was made after they realized two's complement is de facto used exclusively by any platform deemed relevant. So, I wouldn't worry to much about that.

Comment: @bolov: The question is about C, not C++. (A new C standard *might* make a similar change). And the standard describes this in terms of ranges, not sizes. It's just as easy to be precise.

Comment: @KeithThompson my bad, didn't see the C tag

Comment: @chux: Right. `strtol()` will give you all the information you want, but coaxing that information out of the results can be tricky. It quietly ignores leading white space and trailing garbage. and it returns `0` without setting `errno` if no conversion was possible (for example for `"xyz"`). You have to use the `endptr` argument to find out what it actually did.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I verify that an integer value passed in from argv won't overflow?

Use `strtol()` and check the end pointer.  Then check `errno` and maybe a range test

```
if (argc > 1) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long num = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);

  if (argv[1] == endptr) {
    puts("No conversion");
  } else if (errno == ERANGE) {
    puts("Value outside long range");
  #if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN || LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
  } else if (num < INT_MAX || num > INT_MAX) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    puts("Value outside int range");
  #endif
  } else {
    // If code wants to look for trailing junk
    if (*endptr) {
      puts("Non-numeric text");
    } else {
      printf("Success %d\n", (int) num);
    } 
  }
```

Based on [Why is there no strtoi in stdlib.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359)