# How to require argv[1] to be an int?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have to check that `argv[1]` is an `int`, otherwise, print "error".

Any tips? What I have so far clearly is not correct.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    if (argc == 2 && (int) argv[1] > 0)
    {
        printf("Hello, %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add the `[cs50]` tag. Otherwise, many will not know what `string` is as that is not a standard C type.

Comment: Since `string` is required to be a compatible type, it's probably better to just use `char *argv[]` and make the code more general.

Answer (score 7):

The `argv` array is an array of strings, you cannot usefully *cast* that to an integer since it will give you the integer variant of the *pointer.*

What you need to do is use a function like `strtol` to convert the string to a number. The following complete program contains a function that will do that for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checkStrLong(char *num, long *pValue) {
    // Attempt conversion, base ten, get address of first invalid character.

    char *nextCh;
    long val = strtol (num, &nextCh, 10);

    // Reject empty string, ensure whole string was used.

    if ((nextCh == num) || (*nextCh != '\0'))
        return 0;

    // Pass back value.

    *pValue = val;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    long val;

    int len, maxLen = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((len = strlen(argv[i])) > maxLen) {
            maxLen = len;
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (checkStrLong(argv[i], &val)) {
            printf ("%-*s: %ld\n", maxLen, argv[i], val);
        } else {
            printf ("%-*s: <INVALID>\n", maxLen, argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following transcript shows it in action for a few test values:

```
pax> ./testprog 1 -7 42 314159 44.2 21guns hello one23 ""
1     : 1
-7    : -7
42    : 42
314159: 314159
44.2  : <INVALID>
21guns: <INVALID>
hello : <INVALID>
one23 : <INVALID>
      : <INVALID>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should somehow convert string to int.

You could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181501) where they recommed using `strtol()`, which supports error checking.

From the man page:

> The implementation may also set errno to EINVAL in case no conversion was performed (no digits seen, and 0 returned).

So basically you should check errno. If it equals to EINVAL, it means there were no numbers to convert.

Additionally, if you want to print the error set at `errno`, you could use [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html#:%7E:text=DESCRIPTION%20top,a%20colon%20and%20a%20blank.).

---

It's a good practice to check the return value, know what each case may mean, and to print the error msg with `perror()` in case some error occurred. It's good for you, so you familiarize with the tools you're using, it makes the software more robust, and in case the user makes a mistake somewhere (or anything bad happens), the user will receive some feedback on it. Basically, it's a win-win-win situation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like using [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) for scenarios such as this...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int num;

    if ((argc != 2) || (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num) != 1)) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

We check if there are 2 args then we use sscanf to convert argv at 1 to an int and check if it is a number.