# Trailing newline when using scanf() to take string input with whitespace

Tags: c, printf, scanf, trailing-newline

I am getting problem when using `scanf()` to take int input, then move to take a whole string that also accept whitespace in it. But somehow the `scanf()` take place first before the `printf()` even showed up. Still playing around with either `scanf()` and `fgets()` for proper solutions

Here is my snippet code

```c
int age; char name_user[35];
printf("age\t: "); scanf("%d\n",&age);
printf("name\t: "); scanf("%[^\n]%*s", name_user);
printf("result\t: %s is %d years old\n",name_user,age);
```

with the output like this

```
age    : 30
hotpotcookie
name   : loremipsum
result : hotpotcookie is 30 years old
```

are there any workarounds for the input `hotpotcookie` take place in the `name` output? so it could be similar like this

```
age    : 30
name   : hotpotcookie
result : hotpotcookie is 30 years old
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"\n"` consumes 0 or more white-spaces until a non-white-space is detected.  This means `scanf()` will not return at the end-of-line as it is looking for white-spaces after a `'\n'`.

---

`scanf("%d\n",&age);` does not return until detecting non-white-space after the numeric input.

Use `scanf("%d",&age);`.

---

`scanf("%[^\n]%*s", name_user);` also risks buffer overflow.
Use a *width* as in `scanf(" %34[^\n]", name_user);`

---

Better code checks the return value from `scanf()` before using the object(s) hopefully populated by the scan.

---

Even better code does not use `scanf()`.  Instead use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input into a string and then parse with `strotl()`, `sscanf()`, etc.

Comment: I ended up using `fgets()` for all the inputs now, and removing any trailing newline with `name_user[strcspn(name_user, "\n")] = 0;`. and finally using `strotl` as the int value. worked like charm

Comment: @hotpotcookie [Why is there no strtoi in stdlib.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359) may be useful.