# How to convert float to int according to the current rounding direction?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, type-conversion, rounding

How to convert `float` to `int` according to the current rounding direction?

There are the `lrint` and `llrint` functions (C11, 7.12.9.5). However, their return values have types `long int` and `long long int`. Why there is no version for `int`?

Comment: Also, note that an `int` is only guaranteed by the C Standard to be at least 16 bits, so conversion from a 32-bit floating-point type may have been considered (by the committee who defined the `xrint()` functions) to be too dodgy. A `long int` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, IIRC,

Comment: @AdrianMole Re: "simple cast": consider `lrintf((long)INT_MAX+130)`. The `(long)INT_MAX+130` is out of `int` range. Hence, a native conversion to `int` is expected to raise `FE_INVALID`. However, the `int i = (int)lrint(f);` won't raise `FE_INVALID`.

Comment: @AdrianMole `(int)lrint(f)` UB

Comment: @0___________ Agreed - comment gone.

Comment: @pmor, why did you use `lrintf()` to convert a `float` and not `lrintf()`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Initially I used `lrintf`. Then while comparing results obtained from ARM's `fcvtzs` instruction (and similar instructions for other rounding modes) I've noticed that Invalid FP exception may be missing. Hence, I wondered why there is no `irintf` and asked this question. While waitning an answer I wrote `irintf` myself (it calls `lrintf` and then checks if the result is in the `INT_MIN..INT_MAX` range; if not it raises Invalid FP exception and returns 0).

Comment: @pmor For clarity I meant "why did you use `lrint()` to convert a `float` and not `lrintf()`" and it is apparently you took the comment correctly like that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Consider this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77726683/1778275).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because `int` is quite small and you can easily write such a function yourself.

```
int irint(double x)
{
    #if (LONG_MAX > INT_MAX && LONG_MIN < INT_MIN)
    long result = lrint(x);
    #else
    long long result = llrint(x);
    #endif

    if(result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN) 
    {
        feraiseexcept(FE_INVALID);
        return 0;
    }
    return (int)result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to convert `float` to `int` according to the current rounding direction?

Create a helper function that calls `lrintf()` and add desired error handling per C spec: "If the rounded value is outside the range of the return type, the numeric result is unspecified and a domain error or range error may occur.".
I recommend against using `irintf()` in case that comes out later.

```
#incldue <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int my_irintf(float x) {
  long y = lrinf(x);
  // Add desired error handling here when int/long ranges differ.
  #if LONG_MAX > INT_MAX || LONG_MIN < INT_MIN 
    // Example
    if (y > INT_MAX || y < INT_MIN) { 
      errno = ERANGE;
      y = (y > INT_MAX) ? INT_MAX : INT_MIN;
    } 
  #endif
  return (int) y;
}
```

Some systems [raise `FE_INVALID`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lrint.3.html) like:

```
    if (y > INT_MAX || y < INT_MIN) { 
      fesetexcept(FE_INVALID);
      y = (y > INT_MAX) ? INT_MAX : INT_MIN;
    }
```

Given implementation defined functionality with `lrintf()` on errors, `my_irintf(float x)` could benefit with likewise conditional code per implementation.

---

> Why there is no version for `int`?

No `strtoi()` exists in the standard library either.  I suspect for similar reasons.
See [Why is there no strtoi in stdlib.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181432/2410359).

Comment: There is no `strtoi`, however, there is, for example, `atoi`.