# recreation of atoi function max long long error

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, overflow, atoi

I'm having an issue in the output although I defined the macro for max long long to treat overflow but it still gives me a the wrong output

```c
# define LLONG_MAX 9223372036854775807LL
```

as you can see here the macro for the max long long

```c
#include "libft.h"

static int  iswhitespace(char c)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'
        || c == '\r' || c == '\v' || c == '\f')
        return (1);
    return (0);
}
```

function for only white spaces

```c
static int  ft_result(int count, long long int n, int sign)
{
    if (count > 1)
        return (0);
    else if (n > LLONG_MAX && sign == -1)
        return (0);
    else if (n > LLONG_MAX && sign == 1)
        return (-1);
    else
        return (n * sign);
}
```

I think the issue lays here in this function that calculates the results

```c
int ft_atoi(const char *str)
{
    int                 i;
    unsigned long long  n;
    int                 sign;
    int                 count;

    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    sign = 1;
    count = 0;
    if (str == NULL || (str != NULL && *str == '\0'))
        return (0);
    while (iswhitespace(str[i]))
        i++;
    while (str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '+')
    {
        if (str[i] == '-')
            sign *= -1;
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        n = (n * 10) + (str[i++] - '0');
    return (ft_result(count, n, sign));
}
```

for the main function I think the logic is solid if there is a potential segfault please point it out

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("my atoi: %d || original : %d",ft_atoi("9999999999999999999999999"),atoi("9999999999999999999999999"));
}
```

as you can see this is only the comparison between the functions
output:

my `atoi`: 1241513983 || original : -1

Comment: `n > LLONG_MAX` can never be true. The type of `n` is `long long int`. `LLONG_MAX` is the maximum value a `long long int` can have. A `long long int` cannot have a value greater than its maximum value. If an input is going to overflow, it overflows in the calculation in `ft_atoi` before you call `ft_result`, and you cannot detect that overflow in `ft_result`. You need to detect the overflow perform you perform the arithmetic operation that would make it overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you so much for the  clarification 
than i need to treat the overflow inside the calculations and thanks for your time

Comment: @EricPostpischil if possible can you propose a solution

Comment: The [atoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) description says that "If the value of the result cannot be represented, i.e. the converted value falls out of range of the corresponding return type, the behavior is undefined." It's hard to recreate that.

Comment: My suggestion is to switch to  [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), which has a much better defined behavior.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Switching to `strtol()` is a good first step, yet since OP wants to convert to an `int`, a few more steps are useful than only [`(int) strtol(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359).

Comment: i dont have the right to use functions i didint recreate my self ,but thanks so much for taking the time means a lot

Comment: im only trying to replicate the overflow test case so it shows - when it overflows in long long

Answer (score -1, accepted):

okay i think i fixed it thanks for the help if anyone wondering this was the solution

libft.h contains:
#include <limits.h>
i didint define my own macro

```c
#include "libft.h"

static const char   *skipwhitespace(const char *c, int *sign)
{
    while (*c == ' ' || *c == '\t' || *c == '\n'
        || *c == '\r' || *c == '\v' || *c == '\f')
        c++;
    if (*c == '-' || *c == '+')
    {
        if (*c == '-')
            *sign = -1;
        c++;
    }
    return (c);
}

int ft_atoi(const char *str)
{
    int                 i;
    unsigned long long  n;
    int                 sign;

    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    sign = 1;
    if (str == NULL || (str != NULL && *str == '\0'))
        return (0);
    str = skipwhitespace(str, &sign);
    while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
    {
        n = (n * 10) + (str[i++] - '0');
        if (n > LLONG_MAX && sign == 1)
            return (-1);
        if (n > LLONG_MAX && sign == -1)
            return (0);
    }
    return (n * sign);
}
```

i made the test case inside the calculations and use the pointer to skip whitespaces and signs

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("my atoi: %d || original : %d",ft_atoi("9999999999999999999999999"),atoi("9999999999999999999999999"));
}
```

output:
my atoi: -1 || original : -1

and if anyone wonder why I don't use libraries im not allowed to use a function I didn't recreate the printf is only for testing by my side

Comment: Code needs re-work: 1) `if (n > LLONG_MAX && sign == 1)` does not detect all overflow of the previous `n = (n * 10) + (str[i++] - '0');`  (try `n = 2049638230412172402u`; then `n*10`) 
 2) `n * sign` is an _unsigned_ multiplication.  3) Conversion of `unsigned long long` to `int` results implementation defined results due to the value outside `int` range - certainly not a 0, -1 as in early overflow detection 4) `str != NULL` not needed as prior test takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

`if (n > LLONG_MAX && sign == 1)` makes more sense as `if (n > INT_MAX && sign == 1)`, yet code still has at least these problems:

Consider that `int` and `long long/unsigned long long` may be the same width, so using `(unsigned) long long` does not portably help solve `int ft_atoi(const char *str)` as it does not certainly provide additional range over `int`.

Pedantically: `INT_MAX == ULLONG_MAX` may be the same.

In any case, a wider type is not needed.

**Overflow not prevented**

`while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') n = (n * 10) + (str[i++] - '0');` risks overflow and *undefined behavior* (UB).

Instead, test if `(n * 10) + (str[i++] - '0')` may overflow.

```
while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
  int digit = str[i++] - '0';
  if (n >= LLONG_MAX/10 && 
      (n > LLONG_MAX/10 || digit > LLONG_MAX%10)) {
    ; Handle overflow with TBD code
  }
  n = n*10 + digit;
}
```

**Accumulating the positive magnitude fails for `LLONG_MIN/INT_MIN`**

`n * sign` does not well return `INT_MIN` as there is no `n` such that `n * -1` results in `INT_MIN` is a portable well defined manner.

---

Alternative that does not resort to wider types:

Tested code that does **not** use types wider than `int`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int ft_atoi(const char *str) {
  const unsigned char *ustr = (const unsigned char*) str;

  // Avoid calling is...() with negative values.  Use unsigned char * access.
  while (isspace(*ustr)) {
    ustr++;
  }

  unsigned char sign = *ustr;
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    ustr++;
  }

  int sum = 0;
  bool empty = true;
  bool overflow = false;
  while (isdigit(*ustr)) {
    empty = false;
    int digit = *ustr++ - '0';
    if (sum <= INT_MIN / 10
        && (sum < INT_MIN / 10 || digit > -(LLONG_MIN % 10))) {
      sum = INT_MIN;
      overflow = true;
      break;
    }
    // Accumulate the negative magnitude
    sum = sum * 10 - digit;
  }

  if (empty) {
    return 0;  // Maybe set errno too?
  }

  if (sign != '-') {
    if (sum < -INT_MAX) {
      sum = INT_MAX;
      overflow = true;
    } else {
      sum = -sum;
    }
  }

  if (overflow) {
    // Maybe set errno to ERANGE?
    return sum;
  }

  // Optional
  if (*ustr != '\0') {
    ; // Maybe set errno to indicate trailing non-numeric junk?
  }

  return sum;
}
```